# CodeIgniter 2.x set_cipher and set_flashdata cannot be used together

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I try to use `set_cipher` and `set_flashdata` together in CodeIgniter, `flashdata` is not set and a php error is logged.

To reproduce this on a ***fresh*** CI:

Change the following `config.php` lines (changes from default CI config):

```
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
$config['log_threshold'] = 1; // To log the error 
// Encryption key should be set, just set anything, for example:
$config['encryption_key'] = 'HjyePR4FPF70vHKaHTl8jZ0hSMgOu5bW';
```

Controller (Simplified as much as I could):

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct(){parent::__construct();}

 function index()
 {
 $this->load->library('session');
 $this->load->library('encrypt');

 $this->encrypt->set_cipher(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH);
 $this->encrypt->encode('message');

 $this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');
 }

}
```

Then simply open the controller in browser and refresh page, you will see `flashdata` is not set, and the following error is logged in CI application log folder if it has the right permission:

> Severity: Notice  --> unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 286 bytes /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/final/system/libraries/Session.php 741

**1. Is this a CodeIgniter bug or am i doing anything wrong?**

**2. What should I do for this to work?**

`P.S. had to change cipher because default encryption result was too long for a message I needed to encrypt, but I wanted to use default method for anything else CI uses`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**A1:** Both.

It's not a bug per se, but definitely bad design. The CI2 session library does depend on the same `CI_Encrypt` instance that is `$this->encrypt`. So, when the session library is already using it and you change the cipher in the middle of that process, it is indeed you breaking it.

**A2:** Load another instance of the Encryption library for your own usage.

Like this:

```
// You can use $this->encrypter afterwards
$this->load->library('encrypt', NULL, 'encrypter');
```

However, length of the resulting cipher-text is a really bad reason to change the encryption algorithm.

Comment: didn't expect an answer from you Narf (i know you from CI community), thank you very much for taking time to help us CI newbies in stackoverflow, i was just waiting for 3.0.1 or 3.0.2 to move to CI 3 as i was afraid there might be some huge  hidden bugs, wish you the best in life